# How to install pyodbc 64-bit?

Tags: python, mysql, odbc, pyodbc

I have Python 2.7, MySQL 5.5, MySQL ODBC Connector 5.1, and pyodbc all installed on my computer, which is running Windows 7, 64-bit...

Only problem is that everything is installed as 64-bit except pyodbc, which is 32-bit.

When using easy_install to download pyodbc, it automatically downloads the 32-bit version.
Thus, when I try to connect to my database using:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 DRIVER};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=test;UID=root;PWD=password')
```

I get the error:

```
Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)
```

And when I try to specify a DSN with:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=dsn_name;etc...')
```

I get the error:

```
The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application (0) (SQLDriverConnect)
```

This link tells me that this is due to the 32/64-bit mismatch, as expected:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms712362(v=vs.85).aspx

So I have two questions:

1) Is it possible to force easy_install to download the 64-bit pyodbc, or is it possible to download the 64-bit pyodbc manually?

2) If the above is not possible, is it possible to configure the DSN to allow for this using the Microsoft ODBC Data Source Administrator window.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a list of "unofficial" Python modules [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

PyODBC is one of those that have been compiled for 64bits.

Also, make sure you're using the correct version of the ODBC Administrator. The default will be for 64bit drivers, but you can use 32bit drivers with `%windir%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`

Comment: I've tried that installer, but I keep getting the error message "Python version 2.7 required, which was not found in the registry" even though I've located Python 2.7 in my registry. Is there a way to specify where in the registry the installer should check?

Comment: Is your python installation 32bit?

Comment: No, my python installation is 64-bit.

Comment: However, when I download the 32-bit mysql odbc connector, and used odbcad32.exe, the DSN connection worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I spend a lot time to find out why **pyodbc** can't see 64 bit ODBC driver
because I confused between bitness of Windows. So I will make it clear that

Python 32 bit + pyodbc 32 bit (default when install from pip) will read driver from `%windir%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`

Python 64 bit + pyodbc 64 bit (you have to download from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)) will read driver from `%windir%\System32\odbcad32.exe`