# Azure-django pip pyodbc for 64 bit

Tags: python, django, azure, pip, pyodbc

I use this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-ptvs-django-sql/) for config Azure Sql Server (sql_server.pyodbc) for my website. I use Python 64 bit. pyodbc - used for 32 bit.

If I use sql_server.pyodbc, error is

```
Unknown command: 'syncdb'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
The Python REPL process has exited
```

How I can change pip pyodbc to 64 bit, or used anther pip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a answered thread about `How to install pyodbc 64bit` that can help solving the issue. Please refer to the thread [How to install pyodbc 64-bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11108862/how-to-install-pyodbc-64-bit).

You can find the 64bit pyodbc whl file in the `unoffical` python module list at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ and try to use it.

If it not works, I suggest you can try to use the `pymssql` package instead of the `pyodbc` package for Azure SQL Database, please refer to the doc https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-develop-python-simple-windows/.

Answer (score 0):

Download sql_server source package, and run "python setup.py install"